# How to split a string every certain character?

Tags: php

Not a php guru here.

I have a string:

```
works/but/needs/splitting
```

I'd need the output in a ul list

```
<ul>
  <li>works</ul>
  <li>but</li>
  <li>needs</li>
  <li>splitting</li>
<ul>
```

I have been looking into `explode("/", $text);` and tried

```
$originalstring = "works/but/needs/splitting";
    $delimiter = "/";
    if(strpos($originalstring,$delimiter) &gt; 0){
```

But I just don't know much of php and I can't work it out

Comment: you need `explode` https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp read this docu

Comment: @Beginner a user provided me with an answer, was simple indeed, thanks

Comment: $originalstring = "works/but/needs/splitting";
    $delimiter = "/"; echo "<ul>";
    $words=explode("/", $text); foreach($words as $word){ echo "<li>".$word."</li>"; } echo "</ul>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I might not understand your questions, But split by / is this

```
   $originalstring = "works/but/needs/splitting";
    $pieces = explode("/", $originalstring);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($pieces  as $pi){
  echo '<li>'.$pi.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$originalstring = "works/but/needs/splitting";

$e=explode('/',$originalstring); //creates the array ($e) of each element

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($e as $each){ //loop the array ($e)
  echo '<li>'.$each.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Ok got it, I need explode in order to set each word after / in an array, and then I simply loop over it for the <li>, makes total sense. Thanks a lot. Accepting